# Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

In my T-SQL select there appears to be an error with my datetime

```
select 
    t.F47, t.F53, t.F40, t.F162, t.F163,
    N'10' as kostenart, t.F39, t.F2, t.F5,
    convert(nvarchar, cast(t.F9 as datetime), 112),
    t.PARID, 20170928135800 as exportzeitstempel  
from 
    T_TRANS6 as t 
where 
    t.F20 = N'Erledigt' 
    and t.F9 < convert(datetime, '01.09.2017 00:00:00', 104)
```

The error message is German and it says:

> Meldung 242, Ebene 16, Status 3, Zeile 1
>   Bei der Konvertierung eines nvarchar-Datentyps in einen datetime-Datentyp liegt der Wert außerhalb des gültigen Bereichs.

I tried to translate this to:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value."

I really don't know how I did from so thanks for any help guys

Comment: Looks like you are casting F9 as datetime in your select, you probably also need to do that in your where clause as well.

Comment: @JacobH Hey thanks for your time, helping me dont I do that already ?

Comment: I am not seeing a cast function in your where clause on t.F9...

Comment: The message in English is actually: "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value."

Comment: On a typical german installation of SQL server a `CAST('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss' as datetime)` will usually work as it is the local standard format. `CONVERT` with the 104 third parameter will actually try to convert a datetime to a varchar in the given format.

Comment: @Brett Thanks Brett !

Comment: Have you tried altering the statement to see whether it's the conversion in your where clause or the cast in your select?

Comment: @Adwaenyth thanks for your time, emm yes it actually has to since everything in the db is varchar

Comment: Looks like you have an invalid date in `F9`. It sounds like a date such as Febuary 31st, or perhaps a date in the year 0000 or something like that. Depending on your sql server function, you can find the offending date using `TRY_CONVERT`.

Comment: @HoneyBadger 'try_convert' is not recognized as the name of an integrated function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is triggered by `cast(t.F9 as datetime)`.

Please do : `SELECT getdate();` to get the implicit "datetime to string" convertion format.

WARNING : Implicit convertion format are set at the instance level. It can differ from a server to another, even in the same compagny...

This will gives you someting like `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or ...

The given format is the one expected and **required** for all F9 of TRANS6 table records!!

A single TRANS6.F9 with a wrong formating patern will raise this ERROR. So analyse your F9 data, find the concerned rows, clean them and retry...

NOTE : CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), getdate(),112) get a string like `YYYYMMDD` (Ex : '20170928') witch is the only sortable string format of dates...

EDIT : F9 = '2016.10.30' and Implicit convertion expect '2016-10-30' !!

Try this :

```
select 
    t.F47, t.F53, t.F40, t.F162, t.F163,
    N'10' as kostenart, t.F39, t.F2, t.F5,
    convert(nvarchar, convert(datetime,t.F9,102), 112),
    t.PARID, 20170928135800 as exportzeitstempel  
from 
    T_TRANS6 as t 
where 
    t.F20 = N'Erledigt' 
    and t.F9 < convert(datetime, '01.09.2017 00:00:00', 104)
```

Does it works?

Comment: So I did the SELECT getdata() this is what comes out: 2017-09-28 15:12:04.050

Comment: the data in my F9 looks like this 2016.10.30