# How to add a number to a year TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to add a number to my date

For example I have column **F9** which contains a date **2015.10.17** and I have a column **F49** that has a number in it **10**.

The end result should be **2025.10.17** so the number should only be added to the year and that’s it.

**All three columns are of typ varchar**

I have tried to do it as simple as possible but that does not work

```
UPDATE A.dbo.B
SET F29 = F9 + F49
```

Answer (score 2):

If column type Data/datetime

```
UPDATE A.dbo.B SET F29 = DATEADD(year,F49,F9)
```

or this

```
 F29  = CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(F9,1,4) as INT) + F49 as VARCHAR(4)) + SUBSTRING(F9,5,LEN(F9))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but all fields are from type varchar

Comment: Question says contains a date.

Comment: Use TRY_CAST or TRY_CONVERT

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEADD like below

```
UPDATE A.dbo.B
SET F29 = dateadd(year,F49,F9)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but all fields are from type varchar

Answer (score 0):

Test the functionality  using below script:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (F9 VARCHAR(20), F49 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('2015.10.17', '10')

SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, CAST(t.F49 AS INT), CAST(t.F9 AS DATETIME))
FROM   @Table AS t
```

And finally use following script to update:

```
UPDATE A.dbo.B
SET F29 = DATEADD(YEAR, CAST(t.F49 AS INT), CAST(t.F9 AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use roughly the **exact same logic** discussed in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469204/conversion-of-a-varchar-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of). You convert the F9 column as before, apply the dateadd function to it to add F49 as years, and then convert the result back to char(10) using the appropriate format. **OR** you could just fix your schema and never have to deal with these self-created problems.